# SQL Server Management Studio 17.7 AutoRecover NOT IN THIS VERSION

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am tearing my hair out because I was working on some SQL scripts and I executed them to ALTER stored procedure, however when I came in this morning I have lost all my work, it was showing the previous day's script. Somehow it didn't save even though I watched it Execute Successfully Completed!.

Now I thought that using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio v17.7 there will be an auto recovery temp folder with SQL files somewhere, and from looking online its states to go here; C:\Users[User]\Documents\SQL Server Management Studio\Backup Files\Solution1\ and you will see Autorecovery.sql files lots of them.

However this is completely empty, and I got no idea where clever Microsoft has moved this new location too or removed it all together. I went to settings in my SQL studio under Tools->Options->Environment->AutoRecover and both are ticked for "Save AutoRecover Info every 5 minutes" and "keep autorecover info for 7 days". Which tells me it is somewhere on my PC.

I then thought that I might have lost my work and though it would be a good idea to test this scenario on some new scripts and guess what the folder path still shows empty whilst using MSSMS so I got no idea how to utilise this auto recovery feature for the future.

Any ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have realised the only way to make sure you are safe is to have a folder specified with all your scripts stored there.

This way the autosave only works when you have saved the file prior not unsaved files, so it will be a case of Save + Execute.

I have lost my work for now, but this is why people learn from there mistakes.

Answer (score 3):

Try searching in visual studio directories if you have it installed  :

`C:\Users\<your_user>\Documents\Visual Studio <your_version_visual_studio>\Backup Files\Solution1`

Comment: No none of the files are there.

Comment: Try to write a query in the management studio and check that there is a file @Kiel

Comment: And dont close query

Comment: Please explain on query to check if there is a file, this could help me lots.

Comment: For SSMS 2017 it's "Visual Studio 2015"

Answer (score 1):

SSMS 2017 seems to just keep the recovery files in `%TEMP%\` (with name ~vsXXXX.sql)